# escape vs encodeURIComponent

Tags: javascript

I know that `escape` is deprecated, but what is the corresponding alternative that generates the same result?

In this case, I'm sending data to an API which expects that `ä` turns in to `%E4`, and not `%C3%A4`.

```
console.log(escape('ä'), encodeURIComponent('ä')); //%E4, %C3%A4
```

Comment: There isn't a generic JS funcion that's exactly the same.